# Relation between nodes in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, relations

i'm currently working on a mathproblem in "discrete mathematics for computing". I'm a little behind and have some trouble with one question.

"Let ∼ be a relation defined on the nodes on a graph G(N, E), such that
u ∼ v if there exists a path from u to v. Show that ∼ is a equivalences relation
on N. What is the equivalence classes of ∼?"

So i presume i need to find out if the Relation is Symmetric, reflexive and Transitive. But i'm not really sure how to handle it.

I have G(N,E), which is graph of (nodes, edges). u and v are nodes, and there is a relation ~ between them. is that right?

So it looks like this  o------o ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have drawn is a single edge, but the relation itself is about paths between two nodes, i.e. a series of nodes between the two nodes that are all connected by edges.

For this relation what does it mean to be symmetric, reflexive, transitive?

Comment: I'm not sure actually. i understand the symmetric relation (i think). u R v is equivalent to v R u, which in this relation is true. Transitive by definition is when x R y and y R z is quivalent to x R z. But in this relation i cant see how that works.. The same for Reflexive.

Comment: In words, transitivity in this relation would read "If there is a path from $x$ to $y$ and a path to $y$ to $z$, then there is path path from $x$ to $z$".  Can you show that this is true ?  Reflexive would read "There is a path from $x$ to $x$".  Does that sound right ?

Comment: What i see is a path from u------------v 
This is Symmetric since it goes both ways. I cant figure out how to show that there is a path from i.e u to w. Neither a path from u to u (reflexive).

Comment: Ok, so i've searched around a bit.. and i see that a node is connected to itself by a path of length 0. Can someone explain why this is? So ok, the graph is reflexive. Still have problems figuring out the transitive thing..

Comment: If there's a path from u to v and also a path from v to w then there is a path from u to w (via v).